# ARM template output private ip of private-endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

Deploying a private endpoint and need the private ip address as output, but cannot seem to get value query right.
Below results in "The template output 'hostname' is not valid: The language expression property    | 'privateIPAddress' has an invalid array index.. (Code:DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed)

```
    "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', parameters('privateEndpointName'))).networkInterfaces.privateIPAddress]"
```

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have few private endpoints integrated with private DNS zone.
The private IP is available on the `customDnsConfigs` property (Not a networking expert tho but it matches the network interface IP).

```
{
  "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', parameters('privateEndpointName')), '2021-08-01').customDnsConfigs[0].ipAddresses[0]]"
}
```

Comment: `customDnsConfigs` does not appear to be populated on an incremental (second+) deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am able to obtain the private IP address associated with the private endpoint and it looks a bit convoluted due to having to work around some difficulties in Azure.

The first difficulty is that you cannot directly get at the properties of the child resource `.networkInterfaces` from the perspective of the provider `Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints`. The reference will only provide the resource ID for the network interface.

The second difficulty is that one cannot nest a call to `reference()` inside another call to `reference()`. Azure resource management will report an error like "The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location.".

**This will fail:**

```
"value": "[reference(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', parameters('privateEndpointName')), '2021-02-01').networkInterfaces[0].id, '2021-08-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIpAddress]"
```

The solution I have used is based on a collector pattern from the following page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/azure-resource-manager/advanced-templates/collector#collector-template).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "privateEndpointName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {
          "nicName": {
            "value": "[last(split(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', parameters('privateEndpointName')), '2021-08-01').networkInterfaces[0].id, '/'))]"
          }
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {
            "nicName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "resources": [],
          "outputs": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('nicName')), '2021-08-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "nicIpAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'nested')).outputs.ip.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

**Bonus**
I have a Bicep version the compiles to essentially the same JSON. I work primarily in Bicep these days.

main.bicep

```
param privateEndpointName string

resource privateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: privateEndpointName
}

module networkInterface 'nested.bicep' = {
  name: 'nested'
  params: {
    nicName: last(split(privateEndpoint.properties.networkInterfaces[0].id, '/'))
  }
}

output nicIpAddress string = networkInterface.outputs.ip
```

nested.bicep

```
param nicName string

resource networkInterface 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: nicName
}

output ip string = networkInterface.properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress
```

Comment: That is glorious. Works like a charm. Thank you.